# Divisão em URL AMIGAVEL sem criar pasta

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigavel

Ola, estou cirando um site e começando a trabalhar com URls amigáveis, com essa estrutura consigo realizar o procedimento normalmente e resgatar os valores.

Agora gostaria de criar divisões na URL, por exemplo:

tenho hoje que funciona: site.com/contato e site.com/empresa

mas queria criar tipo: site.com/planos/fibra e site.com/cliente/cadastro.

O 1° exemplo esta funcionando corretamente porem não estou conseguindo aplicar divisões sem usar pastas.

minha estrutura é **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

meu **index.php**

```
 <?php      

 $getUrl = strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_DEFAULT)));
 $setUrl =(empty($getUrl)) ? 'index' : $getUrl;
 $Url = explode('/', $setUrl);

$Url[0] = (!empty($Url[0]) ? $Url[0] : null);
$Url[1] = (!empty($Url[1]) ? $Url[1] : null);
$Url[2] = (!empty($Url[2]) ? $Url[2] : null);


       if (file_exists(REQUIRE_PATH_INC . $Url[0] . '.php')):
            require REQUIRE_PATH_INC . $Url[0] . '.php';
        elseif (file_exists(REQUIRE_PATH_INC . $Url[0] . '/' . $Url[1] . '.php')):
            require REQUIRE_PATH_INC . $Url[0] . '/' . $Url[1] . '.php';
        else:
            require REQUIRE_PATH_INC . '404.php';
        endif;  
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa especificar regras em seu htaccess dessa forma:

> RewriteRule  ^contato$        index.php?area=contato [L]

E em seu arquivo index efetuar uma rotina para carregar os dados por área.

Explicando a regra acima: estou dizendo que qualquer url dentro desse dominio começada com contato deve redirecionar para a página index.php passando como argumento da url a variavel GET area.

> cliente/cadastro e /planos/fibra

Outros exemplos:

> RewriteRule  ^cliente/cadastro$   index.php?area=cadastro_clientes [L]
>
> RewriteRule  ^planos/fibra$       index.php?area=planos [L]

Dentro do seu php é que vai criar um switch com a variável $_GET['area'] e efetuar a separação de conteúdo.

Comment: No código da pergunta, no case do `/cliente/cadastro`, o valor em `url` será `cliente/cadastro`, que na *index.php* é separado em `$Url[0]` e `$Url[1]`. Qual o motivo disso não funcionar?